# Need multi-tenancy feature on Third party framework

Tags: java, xml, apache, osgi, orchestration

we are using third party framework(called as orchestrator which is based on java) for business to business integartion. But it does not have multi-tenancy feature.

So how can we achieve the multi-tenancy feature?? Can we integrated any other tool on our framework to support multi-tenancy??

Any Idea....??

Thanks in Advance

Answer (score 1):

Well, multi-tenancy is quite a broad term, not yet very well defined in the context of OSGi. One solution is something we came up with for an open source project called Amdatu. You might want to have a look to see if it solves your problem: http://www.amdatu.org/confluence/display/Amdatu/Multi-tenancy

Following up on my post, we're now working on a transparent mechanism to do multi-tenancy in a single OSGi container, which makes the whole concept of a tenant rather lightweight. Check out the documentation and code here:
http://www.amdatu.org/confluence/display/Amdatu/amdatu-core+tenant

Answer (score 1):

The Paremus Service Fabric (https://docs.paremus.com/display/SF16/Introduction) - an OSGi private Cloud runtime - allows a collection of dynamically formed OSGi containers - a.k.a. 'fibres' to host one of more Elements (i.e. a Blueprint or a Declarative Service) of one or more distributed Systems - i.e. multi-tenancy in each OSGi Framework and multi-tenancy across the collection of Frameworks.

Strict isolation for co-located assembles within the same framework will be provided by the OSGi subSystems standard in due course. So keep an eye out for this.

If this sort of solution is what your are looking for feel free to ping me further questions.

Richard